Xcode 16.1* / Canvas refresh / option+cmd+p is gone. :-<
the really handy shortcut to refresh the preview canvas in Xcode via keyboard shortcut option+command+p is not available anymore (!?!?).
Also the menu-entry 'Canvas' in the previous versions <16.1 is not anymore.
Did I miss any option to enable this again or was this some kind of silly cleanup driven by Apple?
checked any new Settings...but nothing found which is pointing in that direction.

Xcode 16.1 is in beta. If there is something you think is wrong, report it to Apple. It's not our job to guess what counts as "silly cleanup".

Meanwhile reported to Apple via Feedback. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/15374055

ah....what a relief...with Xcode Version 16.1 beta 3 (16B5029d) the Canvas-Menu/Control/Shortcuts are back! :-)

ah....what a relief...with Xcode Version 16.1 beta 3 (16B5029d) the Canvas-Menu/Control/Shortcuts are back! :-)
